# how to get all attribute name and value from HTML code using awk or sed

Tags: awk, sed

Here is my file that has each line as mentioned below:

```
<a href="abc.com" aria-label="abc ofe" class="abc"><span class="bcd">abc</span><span class="icon"></span></a>
```

here is expected output:

```
href="abc.com" 
aria-label="abc ofe" 
class="abc"
class="bcd"
class="icon"
```

Here is what I got:

awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i)printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NFi?FS:(i<NF?"\n":RS))}'

```
echo "<a href="abc.com" aria-label="abc ofe" class="abc"><span class="bcd">abc</span><span class="icon"></span></a>" | awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i)printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NFi?FS:(i<NF?"\n":RS))}'
```

gives me:

```
<a
href=abc.com
aria-label=abc
ofe
class=abc><span
class=bcd>abc</span><span
class=icon></span></a>
```

Trying to get "attribute" string before double quote
and "attribute value" string between double quote.

Need to use awk or sed for macOS.

Comment: Please do add your attempted code in your question, as your efforts which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have added my code that I tried. I am still trying to figure out how to get correct output. Thank u

Comment: thanks for adding your efforts, could you please do edit expected output also? Just  mention it in form of `<html>` `<body>here is my code goes....</body>` I mean in full html code form that will help us to understand question in better manner.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13
my file has each line with multiple html tag which has multiple attributes. I have removed format. 
<a href="abc.com" aria-label="abc ofe" class="abc"><span class="bcd">abc</span><span class="icon"></span></a> 
This is one line

Comment: yeah but your expected output is not clear, post a sample complete html file with complete tags and details so that we need NOT to prepare it by ourselves, moreover it will easier for us to test our codes once complete html is provided in question.

Comment: Trying to get attribute string before double quote
and attribute value string between double quote.
class="abc ofe" @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Sorry but this is not clear, edit your question with above mentioned details, thank you.

Comment: update my question hope this helps
@RavinderSingh13

Comment: With GNU grep? `grep -Eo '[^= ]+="[^"]+"' file`

Comment: Is `aria-label="abc"` a typo?

Comment: you could try a regexp like: https://regex101.com/r/i8EBLU/1

Comment: @Cyrus  opps fixed it 
grep -Eo '[^= ]+="[^"]+"' this does work. Thank you
looks like I need to learn grep and regex

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, you could try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, set RS(record separator) to different values(shown by OP required in output) and then print respective values.

```
awk -v RS='href="[^"]*"|aria-label="[^"]*"|class="[^"]*"' 'RT{print RT}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk` and a regex:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' FPAT='[^= ]+="[^"]+"' OFS="\n" file
```

Output:

```
href="abc.com"
aria-label="abc ofe"
class="abc"
class="bcd"
class="icon"
```

> `FPAT`: A  regular expression describing the contents of the fields in a record.  When set, gawk parses the input into fields, where the fields
> match the regular expression, instead of using the value of FS as the field separator.

See: `man awk` and [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, **ORS**, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Perl solution:

```
$ cat sharad.txt
<a href="abc.com" aria-label="abc ofe" class="abc"><span class="bcd">abc</span><span class="icon"></span></a>
$ perl -0777 -ne ' while(/\<([^>]+)>/sg){ $a=$1; while($a=~/(\S+?\".+?\")/mg) { print "$1\n" } } ' sharad.txt
href="abc.com"
aria-label="abc ofe"
class="abc"
class="bcd"
class="icon"
$
```